# Expo Error running Xcode iOS Simulator: No iPhone devices available in Simulator

Tags: xcode, react-native, ios-simulator, expo

I'm having an issue running iOS simulator from Expo. I'm seeing these two errors:

```
Trying to open the project in iOS simulator...
Opening iOS simulator
iOS Simulator device failed to boot. Try opening Simulator first, then running your app.
Error installing or running app. Error: Timed out waiting for iOS Simulator device to boot.
```

```
Trying to open the project in iOS simulator...
Booting device in iOS simulator...
There was a problem booting a device in iOS Simulator. Quit Simulator, and try again.
Error installing or running app. Error: No iPhone devices available in Simulator
```

An iPhone 5s with iOS 11.2 is clearly available and works in Xcode simulator with a simple project ran from Xcode which tells me this is an Expo issue.

I'm using:

- Expo version: 3.4.1
- Xcode version: 9.2
- Mac OS: 10.12.6

Please note - I cannot upgrade my OS. So Xcode version 9.2 is what I must use.

Things I've tried:

- set command line tools as correct Xcode version with path /Applications/Xcode.app
- delete all simulators and re-add them
- start simulator before running app / start simulator after running app
- delete all contents under Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/

I know this question has been asked before, but no solid answer has been given. Maybe someone has figured it out since then.

Answer (score 0):

your phone runs a newer version of software, so you won't be able to use Xcode version 9.2, you have to use 11.2 or newer before running it on your own phone.

if you want it to work with a newer version of iOS, you have to link the device files of newer Xcode version to the version you use.

https://community1.pega.com/community/pega-support/question/building-mobile-apps-newer-ios-versions-older-xcode-versions
this link should help you with your problem, just follow their steps

you have to do this because each iOS has its own files which comes with the new versions of Xcode 
I hope this helps you;)

Comment: Looks like this fix is for connected devices. I'm running the iOS simulator.